# class type error while working with generic method in scala

Tags: scala

Below is the code snippet...a bit testing mode code snippet.I am trying to create a method through which i can change the return type.

While calling the method i am getting the exception "class type expected object found"

```
trait A

trait B extends A {
  def aba[T](a:Int):T
}

class D

class C extends B {
  def aba[D](a:Int) = {
    println("asasas")
    new D
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual error in Scala 2.11 is

> :13: error: class type required but D found

Which means that you can't instantiate generic type `D` - your `D` class was shadowed by your `[D]` definition

You also can't override `T` (as a part of your `aba`'s method signature) due to Liskov Substitution Principle as it will change behaviour (and signature) for subclass. However you can define `T` as type member:

```
trait A

trait B extends A {
  type T
  def aba(a:Int):T
}

class D 

class C extends B {
  type T = D
  def aba(a:Int): T = {
    println("asasas")
    new D
  }
}
```